# How to build a "stable" voltage divider?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I'm trying to build a EMG (electromyography) acquisition circuit. In order to power the operational amplifiers I'm using a voltage divider with 6.2k resistances and the voltage from the wall is 18V. When I connect the circuit to the wall, I get readings of +9V and -9V; however, after some minutes the voltages are -6V and +12V. Is this because the voltage divider is "unstable"? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: "Remittances"? WTF is that about? And BTW, what's "EMG"?

Comment: Is this all your circuit or do you have loads connected to V+ and V-?

Comment: EMG as in electro-motor graph (medical diagnostic)? What you're looking for is a voltage reference, not a resistive divider. But there are a lot more problems than that. EMG is far more difficult than you realize, the signal amplitudes are far below the noise pickup of the test lead. And you have to ensure that you do not injure or kill the patient. *Do more research before proceeding* - and I don't mean instructibles or youtube, I mean engineering school at minimum.

Comment: Because the driven circuit is itself sinking power from one of the V rails to ground, and doing so unevenly.  This is a classic mistake: **resistors are not voltage regulators.**

Comment: Remittances = resistances, my computer auto corrected me.
This is only the circuit concerning the power used by the amplification portion of the circuit. Oh and EMG is "electromyography". Thanks for your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using another Op Amp you can achieve a stable voltage divider: [image]
And if you want to attach a bigger load you can add an emitter follower to the output of the Op Amp and by attaching the emitter to the (-) input of the Op Amp it will regulate the Base-Emitter voltage drop away from the ground.
Something like this: [image]

Comment: Just make sure that the op-amp source/sink current is high enough for the load requirements.

Comment: Bruce, your solution works great; however, when I connect the Arduino ground to the voltage divider virtual ground it ceases to be stable. Why does this happen?

Comment: probably because the op amp can't sink enough current to run the arduino did you try it with the added schematic with the transistor as emitter follower?

Comment: Is the 18V source of voltage a (floating) wall-wart or is it something special referenced to ground?

Comment: The source is a wall-wart. The same thing happens with 9V batteries.